# how to load pickle file to numpy array

Tags: python, pickle

I saved Numpy array to pickle file.The shape was (850,32,27).How can I load this pickle file to Numpy array? I tried to look up answer ,however I could not fine any.

Comment: you can use `pickle.load()` to load the pickle file

Answer (score 5):

You can load pickled objects with `np.load()`, setting the parameter `allow_pickle` to `True`.

`np.load('PATH_TO_PICKLE_FILE', allow_pickle=True)`

For more info check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-load-in-python).

Comment: The question was how to extract back the numpy array from the saved pickle file, which it load operation returns a tuple of name and numpy, so required answer would be of the way to extract the numpy array from the tuple

Answer (score 1):

Numpy has a

```
np.save()
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html

and a

```
np.load()
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy.load

routine specifically for this purpose. Using pickle is possible, but it seems like over kill.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [2]: A = np.linspace(0,1,10)                                                                                                                                                                                 

In [3]: np.save("bla.npy",A)                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [4]: B = np.load("bla.npy")                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [5]: B == A                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[5]: 
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True])
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The array is apparently already saved with pickle and needs to be loaded.

Comment: It's the proper way of doing it.

Comment: Maybe but if you don't have a time machine you got to do with what you have.

Comment: I like answers that suggest good practice rather than helping OP do something the wrong way :) +1

Comment: The question was how to extract back the numpy array from the saved pickle file, which it load operation returns a tuple of name and numpy, so required answer would be of the way to extract the numpy array from the tuple

Answer (score 1):

You should load you array into a typle using the commands above, such as `np.load('file', allow_pickle=True)` suggested by Steven, or call:

```
filein0 = open('tensor_name', "rb")
t0 = pickle.load(filein0)

t0 is a tuple {tensor name, numpy array}
```

Then, your required numpy array can be extracted using simple:

```
arr = t0[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way of doing this is:

```
import pickle

with open('my_array.pickle', 'rb') as file:
    arr = pickle.load(file)
```

Comment: The question was how to extract back the numpy array from the saved pickle file, which it load operation returns a tuple of name and numpy, so required answer would be of the way to extract the numpy array from the tuple